# Answers referring to a manual page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, not-an-answer

I ran across [an answer that refers readers to a UNIX manual page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c/105315#105315).

The body of the answer contains no additional information or summary, only the `man 3 swab` command. Should the answer be flagged as "not an answer" by following the same logic as [explained in the discussion of link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165460/175984)? The biggest difference here is that the "link rot" argument that came up in many answers and comments does not apply.

Comment: this looks more like code-only answer, [quite a different beast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146892/165773). Though OP looks like terribly lazy for not making an easy [quote](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/swab.3.html) _"The swab() function copies n bytes from the array pointed to by from to the array pointed to by to, exchanging adjacent even and odd bytes.  This function is used to exchange data between machines that have different low/high byte ordering..."_

Comment: I've been treating many of these as I would someone leaving an answer saying "Google it" with a link to a search query. They seem a little rude, and work against the idea of us having self-contained explanations here.

Comment: I flagged a half a dozen similar answers and the flags mostly ended up 'disputed', but all the answers were deleted by mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer deleted, without further comment.